# How to download an entire directory from a webserver?

Tags: web, download

I want to download the contents of [this page](http://lxr.post-tech.com/source/?v=iphone-u-boot-2010-0512) for study purposes. How can I download only this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
wget -r --no-parent --reject "index.html*" http://lxr.post-tech.com/source/?v=iphone-u-boot-2010-0512
```

Comment: Tried but with no luck. It didn't work.